# HTML Inputs Not respecting CSS Height of containing div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm creating a user interface using the `<input>` tag, specifically with `text` and `button`.
My desired interface is to have two text boxes on top of each other, with a button the height of both text boxes to the right of the stacked boxes.

[image: The Desired Layout]

I am able to achieve this layout with the following HTML and CSS, however the input elements do not seem to be respecting the height defined in their stylesheet.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<div id = "container">
  <div class = "control">
     <input type = "text">
     <input type = "text">
  </div>
  <div class = "control">
     <input type = "button">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* dimensions are simplified here */
#container {
   width: 300px;
}
.control {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
.control input[type=text] {
   height: 50%; /* would expect each box to be 100px tall */
   clear: both;
   width: auto;
}
.control input[type=button] {
   height:100%; /*would expect this button to be the same height as both boxes */
   width: auto;
}
```

I have tried following similar questions such as the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781309/floating-div-blocks-one-div-100-height-next-to-two-stacked-divs-of-50-height), however to no avail. My inputs do follow the pattern I illustrated with the image above, however they do not seem to respect the heights and are misaligned. Is there something inherently disproportionate about HTML 5  controls?

[image: Text Boxes Seem Taller Than Buttons]

Comment: You have an `=` in your css instead of a `:`.

Comment: You know that `height = 50%` is not correct...right?

Comment: TIP: Fix this typo in your `CSS`: `#contaner`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I'll fix that, although that's not the problem I'm having because the code in this post isn't verbatim what's in my project... I slightly modified things like indentation and such to put it on SO, and that was just caught in the crossfire.

Comment: TIP #2: Don't add blank spaces before/after `=` when setting attributes/properties.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes I fixed that typo. I reformatted some of this code for SO, the code in my project uses different class names and is slightly harder to follow so I simplified it for my post on SO. some typos were made, thank you for pointing them out.

Comment: your input tag is not closed off!!!!

Comment: @IPADDRESS it's not mandatory in `HTML 5`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I know that but there is no doctype declared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `input[type=text]` have a different box-model from `input[type=button]`

So you can either set the box-model universally or just on the `input[type=text]`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XSv56/1/)

**CSS**

```
.control {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width:50%;
}
.control input[type=text] {
    height: 50%;
    /* would expect each box to be 100px tall */
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.control input[type=button] {
    height:100%;
    /*would expect this button to be the same height as both boxes */
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and works in all use cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/JBsy4/2/)

HTML

```
<div id = "container">
  <div class = "control">
      <input type = "text"/>
         <br/>
      <input type = "text"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "control">
      <input type = "button"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#contaner {
   width: 300px;
}
.control {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
.control input[type=text] {

   clear: both;
   width: auto;
}
.control input[type=button] {
   height:25%; 
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: `height = 50%;` is wrong.  This didn't fix anything, the height of the button is just adjusted to the default height of the text inputs.

Comment: @JamesMontagne where is `height = 50%;` ?